# Форма не меняет размер Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Установил в дизайне формы размер 1650 * 650, однако при запуске программы размер формы совершенно другой (показано на скриншоте). Примерно 800 * 600. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?

xml код формы:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Filminfo</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Filminfo">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1500</width>
    <height>650</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="palette">
   <palette>
    <active>
     <colorrole role="WindowText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Button">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Light">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Midlight">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Dark">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Mid">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Text">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="BrightText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ButtonText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Base">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Window">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Shadow">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>220</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="127">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
    </active>
    <inactive>
     <colorrole role="WindowText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Button">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Light">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Midlight">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Dark">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Mid">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Text">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="BrightText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ButtonText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Base">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Window">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Shadow">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>220</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="127">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
    </inactive>
    <disabled>
     <colorrole role="WindowText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Button">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Light">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Midlight">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Dark">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Mid">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Text">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="BrightText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>255</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ButtonText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Base">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Window">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="Shadow">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>255</red>
        <green>255</green>
        <blue>220</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="255">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
     <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
      <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
       <color alpha="127">
        <red>0</red>
        <green>0</green>
        <blue>0</blue>
       </color>
      </brush>
     </colorrole>
    </disabled>
   </palette>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Информация</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="2" column="1">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Аннотация</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_5">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="5">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>34</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="2">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="author">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Автор</string>
     </property>
     <property name="scaledContents">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="wordWrap">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="5">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>24</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="6" column="3">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Жанр(ы)</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="1" colspan="2">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="name">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat Black</family>
       <pointsize>16</pointsize>
       <italic>true</italic>
       <bold>true</bold>
       <underline>false</underline>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Название</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_6">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>70</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="5" column="5">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_7">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>35</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="6" column="5">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="7" column="3">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>97</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="3" column="0">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="3">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Дата выхода</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="5" column="3">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Рейтинг</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="4">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="date">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Дата выхода</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="2" rowspan="5">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="annot">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Аннотация</string>
     </property>
     <property name="scaledContents">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
     </property>
     <property name="wordWrap">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="margin">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <property name="openExternalLinks">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="1">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Режиссёр(ы)</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="3" column="1">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>128</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="7" column="1">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_4">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>22</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="5" column="4">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="rating">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Рейтинг</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="6" column="4" rowspan="2">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="genres">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Montserrat</family>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Жанры</string>
     </property>
     <property name="scaledContents">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
     </property>
     <property name="wordWrap">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="3" rowspan="4" colspan="2">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="poster">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Постер</string>
     </property>
     <property name="scaledContents">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="wordWrap">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="7" column="2">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_5">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>368</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: `An error has occurred while reading the UI file at line 338, column 19: Encountered incorrectly encoded content.`

Comment: @PavelGridin 338 линия выглядит так: <red>0</red>. Не знаю что ему могло не понравится в этой строке. При том что у меня никаких ошибок не возникает

Comment: пробовал открывать дизайнерами от qt4.8.4 и qt6.2.4, возможно ошибка в xml который в вопросе

Comment: @PavelGridin Я работаю на версии qt 5.15.2. Не совсем понял что вы имеете в виду под "текстом который в вопросе"

Comment: ну вот который выше приведён, я его просто скопировал в ui-файл и вот такой результат, может символ какой попал и ещё что, попробуйте его обратно в файл сохранить отсюда

Comment: @PavelGridin Вставил код отсюда туда, все работает. Но в процессе тестирования я понял одну вещь: любые изменения в дизайне никак не отражаются в программе. Я сменил задний фон, шрифты, но всё равно вижу старую картинку. Собственно поэтому у меня и не менялась форма. Но вопрос как теперь это починить

Comment: ну, а соответствующий файл ui_*.h  меняется? uic запускается?

Comment: @PavelGridin Понимаю, это сейчас прозвучит максимально глупо, но как это проверить?

Comment: например, если у вас в проекте есть строка `FORMS += a.ui`, то компилятор uic создаст файл ui_a.h, который вы должны использовать в программе для создания класса формы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147116/discussion-between-mswork6-and-pavel-gridin).

Answer (score 0):

Решением проблемы в моём случае стало отключение теневой сборки в настройках проекта Qt Creator